# Load txt into json looping over multiple files using python

Tags: python, json, list, twitter

I want to load multiple *.txt files into json format. Here you see an example of the objects of each file:

```
file_a.txt

{"created_at":"Mon Jan 28 15:01:47 +0000 2019","id":1089901356561977344,"id_str":"1089901356561977344","text":"@oracion_milagro Amen","display_text_range":[17,21],"source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/android\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for Android\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":1089895545043406848,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":"1089895545043406848","in_reply_to_user_id":900042443281883136,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":"900042443281883136","in_reply_to_screen_name":"oracion_milagro","user":{"id":958875486561755136,"id_str":"958875486561755136","name":"Marlene","screen_name":"Marlene15298799","location":null,"url":null,"description":null,"translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":16,"friends_count":156,"listed_count":0,"favourites_count":2435,"statuses_count":1783,"created_at":"Thu Feb 01 01:31:45 +0000 2018","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":true,"lang":"es","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"F5F8FA","profile_background_image_url":"","profile_background_image_url_https":"","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1DA1F2","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/sticky\/default_profile_images\/default_profile_normal.png","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/sticky\/default_profile_images\/default_profile_normal.png","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":{"id":"0177bc687a9ac697","url":"https:\/\/api.twitter.com\/1.1\/geo\/id\/0177bc687a9ac697.json","place_type":"city","name":"Quito","full_name":"Quito, Ecuador","country_code":"EC","country":"Ecuador","bounding_box":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-78.948466,-0.588618],[-78.948466,0.255477],[-78.164897,0.255477],[-78.164897,-0.588618]]]},"attributes":{}},"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"oracion_milagro","name":"Oraci\u00f3n Milagrosa","id":900042443281883136,"id_str":"900042443281883136","indices":[0,16]}],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1548687707449"}
{"created_at":"Mon Jan 28 15:01:50 +0000 2019","id":1089901370503770113,"id_str":"1089901370503770113","text":"https:\/\/t.co\/geLk6b96RH","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/android\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for Android\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":173148248,"id_str":"173148248","name":"Ratman","screen_name":"TheBigRatman","location":"Colombia","url":"https:\/\/www.instagram.com\/rattmaan\/","description":"Rock&Rolla'","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":529,"friends_count":384,"listed_count":2,"favourites_count":11738,"statuses_count":5380,"created_at":"Sat Jul 31 15:32:12 +0000 2010","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":true,"lang":"es","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"131516","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme14\/bg.gif","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme14\/bg.gif","profile_background_tile":true,"profile_link_color":"1B95E0","profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"EFEFEF","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1044462335803490305\/Ua_w6ETq_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1044462335803490305\/Ua_w6ETq_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/173148248\/1547148337","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":{"id":"0161be1b3f98d6c3","url":"https:\/\/api.twitter.com\/1.1\/geo\/id\/0161be1b3f98d6c3.json","place_type":"city","name":"Bogot\u00e1, D.C.","full_name":"Bogot\u00e1, D.C., Colombia","country_code":"CO","country":"Colombia","bounding_box":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-74.483289,3.717432],[-74.483289,4.807135],[-74.004053,4.807135],[-74.004053,3.717432]]]},"attributes":{}},"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/geLk6b96RH","expanded_url":"https:\/\/youtu.be\/9EKi2E9dVY8","display_url":"youtu.be\/9EKi2E9dVY8","indices":[0,23]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"und","timestamp_ms":"1548687710773"}
```

```
file_b.txt

{"created_at":"Mon Jan 28 15:01:46 +0000 2019","id":1089901354154450944,"id_str":"1089901354154450944","text":"Iniciemos el fin de semana con un poco de humor #humor #ojos #vision #ojos #optometry #lol en Bogot\u00e1, Colombia https:\/\/t.co\/naYIBgp8bZ","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/instagram.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eInstagram\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":1434403705,"id_str":"1434403705","name":"Dres Bahamon & Herrera optometria","screen_name":"DrsHerreraBaham","location":"Bogot\u00e1, D.C., Colombia","url":"http:\/\/www.lookmio.com","description":"Equipo profesional en cuidado de la salud visual, tecnolog\u00eda, diagn\u00f3stico y tratamientos \u00f3pticos y quir\u00fargicos. pediatr\u00eda - contactologia - ex\u00e1menes","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":86,"friends_count":235,"listed_count":0,"favourites_count":118,"statuses_count":852,"created_at":"Fri May 17 01:06:42 +0000 2013","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":true,"lang":"es","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"4AB802","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":true,"profile_link_color":"1D4601","profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/3669768174\/5fd75cfe75eea9b5482d56c35e501059_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/3669768174\/5fd75cfe75eea9b5482d56c35e501059_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/1434403705\/1538225244","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[4.5997,-74.0794]},"coordinates":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-74.0794,4.5997]},"place":{"id":"0161be1b3f98d6c3","url":"https:\/\/api.twitter.com\/1.1\/geo\/id\/0161be1b3f98d6c3.json","place_type":"city","name":"Bogot\u00e1, D.C.","full_name":"Bogot\u00e1, D.C., Colombia","country_code":"CO","country":"Colombia","bounding_box":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-74.483289,3.717432],[-74.483289,4.807135],[-74.004053,4.807135],[-74.004053,3.717432]]]},"attributes":{}},"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"humor","indices":[48,54]},{"text":"ojos","indices":[55,60]},{"text":"vision","indices":[61,68]},{"text":"ojos","indices":[69,74]},{"text":"optometry","indices":[75,85]},{"text":"lol","indices":[86,90]}],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/naYIBgp8bZ","expanded_url":"https:\/\/www.instagram.com\/p\/BtLrmzSg_6I\/?utm_source=ig_twitter_share&igshid=w921ke3b2aj0","display_url":"instagram.com\/p\/BtLrmzSg_6I\/\u2026","indices":[111,134]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"es","timestamp_ms":"1548687706875"}
{"created_at":"Mon Jan 28 15:01:47 +0000 2019","id":1089901354968141825,"id_str":"1089901354968141825","text":"Entonces @Avianca decide que la \u201cpreselecci\u00f3n de sillas\u201d no garantiza esa silla seleccionada en su \u2708\ufe0f! La explicaci\u2026 https:\/\/t.co\/kl5Mx2diN5","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":true,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":2851169650,"id_str":"2851169650","name":"Mauricio Castellanos","screen_name":"MaurCast81","location":null,"url":null,"description":null,"translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":27,"friends_count":51,"listed_count":2,"favourites_count":178,"statuses_count":335,"created_at":"Thu Oct 30 10:30:20 +0000 2014","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":true,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1DA1F2","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/749972184630693889\/QpuDJfSN_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/749972184630693889\/QpuDJfSN_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/2851169650\/1467642279","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":{"id":"01230a524360316e","url":"https:\/\/api.twitter.com\/1.1\/geo\/id\/01230a524360316e.json","place_type":"city","name":"Cove\u00f1as","full_name":"Cove\u00f1as, Colombia","country_code":"CO","country":"Colombia","bounding_box":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-75.718829,9.360130],[-75.718829,9.459193],[-75.612003,9.459193],[-75.612003,9.360130]]]},"attributes":{}},"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"extended_tweet":{"full_text":"Entonces @Avianca decide que la \u201cpreselecci\u00f3n de sillas\u201d no garantiza esa silla seleccionada en su \u2708\ufe0f! La explicaci\u00f3n: ninguna! Qu\u00e9 pensar\u00eda el Papa de c\u00f3mo la aerol\u00ednea Papal se caga en los pobres mortales? \u201cNo le hagas el mal al pr\u00f3jimo\u201d\ud83d\ude09","display_text_range":[0,240],"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"Avianca","name":"Avianca","id":274087824,"id_str":"274087824","indices":[9,17]}],"symbols":[]}},"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/kl5Mx2diN5","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/1089901354968141825","display_url":"twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/1\u2026","indices":[117,140]}],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"Avianca","name":"Avianca","id":274087824,"id_str":"274087824","indices":[9,17]}],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"es","timestamp_ms":"1548687707069"}
```

Both files are in the same folder. I want to load both files, read them line by line, and create independent output files in .json format. Here is my code. It only works for the last line of each file.

```
import glob
import numpy as np
import json

path = "C:/Users/onlyme/my_folder"
all_files = glob.glob(path + '/*.txt')

tweets = []

for file in all_files:
    for line in open(file, "r"):
        tweets = json.loads(line)
        parts = file.split(".")
        jsonout_filename = parts[0] + ".json"        
        with open(jsonout_filename,'w') as fou:
            json.dump(tweets,fou)
        with open(jsonout_filename,'r') as fin:
            twts = json.load(fin)
```

Comment: You create tyour output filename inside the loop (`jsonout_filename = parts[0] + ".json"`) but you do the actual writing outside the loop.

Comment: There are undefined variables in the last part of the script. What's `t`?

Comment: You're only writing a single file, what result did you except? By the way, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: thanks. I just changed the variable names. I placed the two "with open..." statements inside of the loop, but then, only the last line gets stored in each file. I know i am missing a tiny thing, but I dont see it. I also started a couple of months ago to learn python and programming